# What is the definition of a "shituki"?

Tags: halacha, rambam, family-members

What is the definition of "shituki"?
This term may be found in Rambam, Mamrim 5:9.

I apologize that I was not able to be more specific in adding contextual 'tags'.

Comment: See Rambam, Issurei Biah 15:12, and Mishna Kiddushin 4:2

Comment: Is the Rambam tag really appropriate here?  While the OP found the word in Rambam, it does not originate there.

Answer (score 8):

Kiddushin 69a (Art Scroll Kiddushin 69a4), The end of the first mishna chapter 4 Asarah Yochasin. There are ten classes of geneology, this is one of them.

> **These are shetukim: Anyone who knows** the identity of **his mother, but
>   does not know** the identity of **his father** <sup>9</sup>

Note 9:

> *Shetuki* literally means "the quieted one" (from the root שתק, *quiet*). [A child without a father is liable to address any adult male as "Father". When he does so], his mother must silence him.
>   (*Rashi*)

Comment: Thus, the child is definitely Jewish, but could be anything from a Cohen to a Mamzer.